# SharePoint Designer 2013 add new columns to custom form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom Edit form that was created using SPD. I had to add new columns to this form and so created few columns. How do I add these columns to the custom form?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the pattern of the existing columns in your existing form to add new fields.

Or edit the Edit form  in SPD and add a new "edit form". That will contain all fields currently in the list and you can copy / paste the relevant code to your original form, then delete the new form.

Comment: thanks for your response. I just followed the pattern and changed the ID to last ID+1.  This looks like a workaround.  Shouldn't  there be a direct method to add form fields?